# python function calculate grades

Tags: python

i want to code python program that calculate grades

first list is final exam grade. second list is homework final grade list.

the wight of the score is 70% for exam grade (list 1)  and 30% for homework grade

```
def func_calc(a,b):

    for i in range(len(a)):
        exam1 = a[i]
        homework1= b[i]
         print(0.70*exam1+0.30*homework1)
    e = [70,80,67,89,100]
    h= [100,80,56,89,100]
    func_calc(e,h)
```

why the list in `main()` not working in the `func_calc`(only one arg sent)?

Comment: can you add your expected output, also if you have a grade in a test < 60, thx!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to indent your `if` statement in your loop. Try

```
    for i in range(len(a)):
        exam1 = a[i]
        homework1= b[i]
        if a[i] < 60:
            print (a[i])
        else:
             print(0.70*exam1+0.30*homework1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it doesn't work as your indentation is quite incorrect. You loop over the grades by index assignign them to unused variables. Than you do something with the index outside of the loop (where it is either undefined or takes the last value of the loop so in this case 4). 
This can be done a lot shorter with a list generator:

```
def func_calc(a,b):
   return [0.7*exam + 0.3*home if exam >= 60 else exam for exam,home in zip(a,b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code indentation is incorrect. Please correct the indentation of if-else part as given below:

```
def func_calc(a,b):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        exam1 = a[i]
        homework1 = b[i]
        if a[i] < 60:
            print (a[i])
        else:
            print (0.70*exam1+0.30*homework1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is your background but maybe it helps to understand better if there is used java/c# syntax. Python use indentation to show what belongs to nested block. As you have `for` and `if` they will be executed sequentially

```
def func_calc(a,b):

    for i in range(len(a)):
        exam1 = a[i]
        homework1= b[i]
    if a[i] < 60:
        print (a[i])
    else:
         print(0.70*exam1+0.30*homework1)
```

rewritten to other language will be executed as

```
void func_calc(a,b){

    for (i = 0; i < a.Length(a); i++){
        exam1 = a[i]
        homework1= b[i]
    }

    if(a[i] < 60){
        print (a[i])
    }
    else{
         print(0.70*exam1+0.30*homework1)
    }
}
```

So simply indent if so it is executed as part of your `for` loop

```
def func_calc(a,b):

    for i in range(len(a)):
        exam1 = a[i]
        homework1= b[i]
        if a[i] < 60:                         # this is indented
            print (a[i])                      # this is indented
        else:                                 # this is indented
             print(0.70*exam1+0.30*homework1) # this is indented
```

Equivalent in java/c# will be

```
void func_calc(a,b){

    for (i = 0; i < a.Length(a); i++){
        exam1 = a[i]
        homework1= b[i]

        if(a[i] < 60){
            print (a[i])
        }
        else{
             print(0.70*exam1+0.30*homework1)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are iterating over all your grades and keep only the last one,  you can fix this with including your `if` statement under your `for` loop

---

also, you can use a list comprehension :

```
exam = [70,80,67,89,100]
homework= [100,80,56,89,100]
[0.7*e + 0.3*h if e > 60 else 0.7* e for e, h in zip(exam, homework)]
```

output:

```
[79.0, 80.0, 63.7, 89.0, 100.0]
```

Comment: no, as it doesn't do anything with the fact that you should return only part of it if student fails

Comment: @Eric yes, I hope now is better

Comment: i don't think the exam counts for 70% if it is the only grade :) unsure though as not specified in question.

Comment: @Eric ths OP says `If the student fails the test then only the test score is calculated.`

Comment: exactly, so it counts as the full grade (i think at least). This is also what is done in the original code, albeit in an incorrect loop

Comment: how come it counts as a full grade? what bout the `calculated` part from the sentence? and how this may be consistent with the other grades?

Answer (score 0):

It's your indentation.
Should be:

```
def func_calc(a,b):

    for i in range(len(a)):
        exam1 = a[i]
        homework1= b[i]
        if a[i] < 60:
            print (a[i])
        else:
            print(0.70*exam1+0.30*homework1)

def main():
    exam = [70,80,67,89,100]
    homework= [100,80,56,89,100]
    func_calc(exam,homework)

main()
```